# ¿Es necesario instalar PHP, Apache y MYSQL aparte de XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, composer

he tenido una duda porque mi profesor me ha pedido instalar los programas de XAMPP, Apache, Composer, MYSQL, NodeJS y Git. El caso es que, al instalar el XAMPP, me han mencionado que con ello ya no es necesario instalar el Apache y MYSQL ya que aparece ahí en conjunto con el XAMPP, pero no sé si realmente no es necesario o aparte del XAMPP debo instalar el Apache y MYSQL (el NodeJS, Git y Composer; aunque este último ya lo descargue aparte y lo vincule con el PHP de XAMPP aunque instale por cualquier cosa aparte el PHP y ya lo tengo en el PATH).
¿Es realmente necesario aparte o ya con solo el XAMPP no es necesario instalar esos dos programas (el Apache y MYSQL)?

Comment: Xampp: [X] cualquier sistema, [A] Apache, [M] MySql/MariaDb, [P] PHP, [P] Perl. O sea, ya trae todo eso integrado. Luego de sus propias páginas web descargas e instalas: [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads), [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en) y [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Answer (score 0):

El XAMPP es un paquete de software que incluye Apache, MySQL, PHP y Perl, entre otros componentes. Al instalar XAMPP, obtendrás una instalación completa de Apache y MySQL, por lo que no es necesario instalarlos por separado.